# Some sufficient conditions for operator to be isometric

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am stuck on some problem. A is operator in finite-dimensional Euclidean space. I need to show that A is isometric operator if:

1. Operator *A* is invertible.
2. $\exists$*v $\neq$ 0: (v, v) = (Av, Av)*
3. $\forall$*a,b: (a, b) = 0 $\Rightarrow$ (Aa, Ab) = 0*

Can you give me some hints? Solution or hints without adjoint operator are most wanted.

Comment: Should condition $2$ be $\exists$ or $\forall$?

Comment: @Mark I don't think so. The problem says there is at least one non-zero vector such that operator doesn't change his length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u$ be an arbitrary vector. Then for all $v\in u^\perp$ we have $(A^*Au,v) = (Au,Av) = 0$. Hence, $A^*Au\in (u^\perp)^\perp = \operatorname{span}\{u\}$. Thus, for each vector $u$ there exists some number $\lambda_u$ such that $A^*Au = \lambda_u u$. The linearity of $A^*A$ now implies that $\lambda_u$ does not depend on $u$. Hence, $A^*A = \lambda I$ for some number $\lambda\ge 0$ (as $A^*A$ is a positive operator). Now, condition 2 implies that $\|v\|^2 = \|Av\|^2 = \|\lambda v\|^2 = |\lambda|^2\|v\|^2$ and thus $\lambda = 1$, meaning that $A^*A = I$. In other words, $A$ is isometric. Condition 1 now ensures that also $AA^* = I$. That is, $A$ is unitary.

Comment: What is $A^*$? Where did it come from in the first line?

Comment: $A^*$ is the adjoint of $A$. If you are messing around with operators and inner products, you should actually know it... If $A$ is a bounded operator between Hilbert spaces $H$ and $K$, then there exists its adjoint, mapping from $K$ to $H$ such that $(Ax,y) = (x,A^*y)$ for all $x\in H$ and all $y\in K$. The operator $A^*A$ is then a positive selfadjoint operator in $H$.

Comment: My classroom teacher didn't told me about adjoint operators so I assume the problem can be solved without them. However, answer is answer. But I still looking for another solution or hints.

Comment: In what space does the operator $A$ act? Is $A$ linear? You didn't say nothing about this (which is actually required).

Comment: Do you at least know that there must be some operator $S$ such that $(Au,Av) = (Su,v)$? This lemma has a name (I forgot it), but follows easily from the Riesz representation theorem.

Comment: See edits. We have no information about if is $A$ linear or if $S$ exists.

Comment: If $A$ is not supposed to be linear, the statement is false. Here is a counterexample: $A : \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, $A(x) = x^3$.

Comment: Well, I think my classroom teacher made a mistake here. Thank you very much.